# Can we find a closed form of the integration $\int_{-\frac{1}2}^{\frac{1}2}\frac{\arcsin^2 x}{x^2+2x+2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can we find a close form of the integration  $I=\int_{-\frac{1}2}^{\frac{1}2}\frac{\arcsin^2 x}{x^2+2x+2}dx$?I have tried and get
$$I=\int_0^{\frac12}\arcsin^2x \cdot d(\arctan (x+1)+\arctan(x-1))$$
but unfortunately 
$$\arctan (x+1)+\arctan(x-1)=\arctan \frac{2x}{2-x^2}$$
Which is not equal to some constant $c$ times $\arcsin x$,(otherwise we can solve it by using Newton-Leibniz formula).